# Does the function $e^x/(1+e^x)$ have a standard name?

Tags: logistic, neural-networks, deep-learning, terminology

Does a function in the form $e^x/(1+e^x)$ have a standard name?  E.g. $y = a + bx$ is a linear function.

Comment: it's the standard logistic function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)

Comment: It is the "Sigmoid" function. More commonly expressed as the equivalent $1 / (1 + e^{- x}).$

Comment: @Bridge "Sigmoid," as suggested by its ending "...oid," is a generic description of any function whose graph is roughly s-shaped.  It therefore is a poor (albeit common) choice of term to use when you really do mean the logistic function.

Comment: @whuber indeed; it is annoying to nowadays have to ask what the person using "sigmoid" actually intends, whereas some time ago it was safe to assume it took its literal meaning.

Comment: @Bridgeburners For example the [inverse probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions) function and [complementary log-log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Complementary_log-log_(cloglog)) link functions are *also* sigmoid functions.

Comment: Stephen Jay Gould's essay "Is the Cambrian explosion a sigmoid fraud?" springs to mind.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It does not have a *standard* name. In different areas of statistics, it has different names.

In the neural networks and deep learning community, it is called the **sigmoid** function. This is confusing for everyone else, because *sigmoid* is just a fancy way of saying "S-shaped" and this function is not unique among S-shaped functions; for example, $\tanh$ is also S-shaped and widely used in neural networks, yet it is *not* commonly termed "sigmoidal" in neural network literature.

In the GLM literature, this is called the **logistic** function (as in *logistic* regression).

If the *logit* function is $$\text{logit}(p)=
\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)=
\log(p)-\log(1-p)=x$$ for $p\in(0,1)$, then $$\text{logit}^{-1}(x)=
\frac{\exp(x)}{1 + \exp(x)}=
\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}=
p$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. This is the reason some people call $\text{logit}^{-1}$ the **inverse logit** or **anti-logit** function. (Thanks, Glen_b!)

Rarely, I've seen the name **expit** used; as far as I can tell, this is a back-formation from the word logit but never really caught on. (Thanks, CliffAB!)

Comment: _arc_ has a specific meaning for inverse trigonometric functions as the inverse of any trigonometric function is, or at least is equivalent to, an angle. It's a pity that this is misunderstood quite often for inverse hyperbolic functions where notations like arcsinh are sometimes encountered. There the inverse does have interpretation as an _area_ and indeed arsinh is better (or asinh). Careful pronunciation may be advisable depending on accent and audience. But _arc_ really can't carry a general meaning of inverse.

Comment: I'd say expit is growing slowly for inverse of logit. But it's still rare in what I read.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for the helpful context about *arc*. Indeed, the Google ngram viewer appears to support your observation about the usage of "expit." https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expit%2Cinverse+logit&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinverse%20logit%3B%2Cc0 But for some reason the largest end year allowed is 2008. :-\